# Is opencl supported in Raspberry Pi for stereo vision applications?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I am currently using the opencv library for implementing stereo vision on the raspberry pi. A colleague of mine is using an odroid sbc supporting opencl for parallel processing of matrices.

Is opencl supported in Raspberry Pi for stereo vision applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer isn't totally straightforward, but I suspect that for your purposes the answer is 'no' at present.

Portable OpenCL on the CPU (I think this will be too slow for your application) does seem to work:
http://parallelplusplus.blogspot.co.uk/2015/10/opencl-on-raspberry-pi-2.html?m=1

But folks seem to be making some progress at getting it running on the GPU:
http://petewarden.com/2014/08/07/how-to-optimize-raspberry-pi-code-using-its-gpu/
https://m.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/3fi2of/is_there_an_opencl_implementation_for_the_pi/

But it could be a while before we see the fruits of their labours.

Comment: Thank you. :) it looks like I'm stuck to just optimizing the code to run at a faster sampling rate